# Read and write many text files

Tags: c++, file-io

I have 100 files in a folder. Is it possible for me to read all the files and write it in other text files automatically? Or else I have to manually key in the path. If it is possible, what functions should I use? Or should I just include counter in my function? This is how I open and write to a file:

```
using namespace std;


string filename;   
string line;
ofstream fout("text1.txt") ;   

void path_enter(){
    cout<<"Please enter the path of your file\n";
    cin>>filename;

    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
    int i=1;

    if (!fin)   
    {
        cout<<"failed\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while (getline(fin,line,'.')){

            cout<<"\nLine"<<i<<" : "<<line<<endl<<endl;
            fout<<"\nLine"<<i<<" : "<<line<<endl<<endl;
            i++;   
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to list all files of a certain directory [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/9173/). So I would propose the following:

- Get the list of all files in this directory.
- Iterate over this list to read.
- And finally for your output you could maybe append a string to the file you read.

To distinguish better between the input and output files, I would save the output files to an other directory.

The following code will return you the list of all files in a given directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
/*
 * @Ipath path to directory
 * @relative true, if the path is a relative path, else false
 */
vector<string> getFiles(string Ipath, bool relative){
    vector<string> list;        //the list that should be returned
    if(relative)                //edit the path, if it is relative
        Ipath = "./" + Ipath;
    //convert the path from string to char*
    char* path = new char[Ipath.length()];
    strcpy(path, Ipath.c_str());
    //initialize the DIR
    DIR *pDIR;
    struct dirent *entry;
    if( pDIR=opendir(path) ){   //check if the path exists, if yes open
        //as long as there is a file left, we didn't look at do
        while(entry = readdir(pDIR)){
            //check if the filename is a valid filename
            if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 ){
                string fE(entry->d_name);         //convert the char* to string
                list.push_back(entry->d_name);    //add the string to the list
            }
        }
        closedir(pDIR);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: hi thank you very much. im so sorry if this sound stupid but can you please explain what does  'if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 )' do?

Comment: Ohh yes sorry, this is not necessary. It checks if the file is invisible, so if the filenames starts with a '.'. I will remove it.

Comment: i have run it but there's an error  cannot convert 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'int' in return|

Comment: Ok.. I found now an old program, that I once used. This should work.

Comment: thanks! but i got lost in your code. i have a few questions more i hope you are patient enough to answer. Ipath is where i should put my directory, is that correct? i dont really understand how it will return the list of files. sigh sorry again

Comment: Yes Ipath is the path to your directory. And with relative you specify if this path is relative (true) or absolute (false). Then I convert the string path to a char* that 'opendir' could use it. To the rest I will add comments in the code.

Comment: I think it should be clear now. If this answer helped you please vote it up and mark it as the solution, that others could see, that your problem is solved.

Comment: yes yes thank you very much for your help! tho i still need to look at it.  anyway thanks a lot!